# Finding dates majority of data fall into (median/ CI?) in R

Tags: r, date, linear-regression, median

I have a dataset containing a column of dates (daily values summed by week) and a column of values representing bird mortality. I need to find out the dates the majority of mortality fall into. The values are not normally distributed with a major peak at the end of July due to increased surveying effort. Some weeks had zero observed mortalities.

| Date Observed | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-08 | 4 |
| 2022-05-22 | 1 |
| 2022-05-29 | 5 |
| 2022-06-05 | 1 |
| 2022-06-12 | 10 |
| 2022-06-19 | 64 |
| 2022-06-26 | 4 |
| 2022-07-10 | 800 |
| 2022-07-17 | 300 |
| 2022-07-24 | 207 |
| 2022-07-31 | 3002 |
| 2022-08-07 | 2 |

I'm not new to R but I am evidently rusty on my statistical analysis. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I have tried simple things: estimating median of Date Observed (using `summary` and `summaryStats(DateObserved, quartiles=TRUE)[[7]]` from EnvStats library. But after plotting the values over time, I do not think the resulting quartiles look right. Also, tried fitting a linear model.

Thank you sincerely in advance for any leads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df_1 <- read_tsv(file="DateObserved Value
2022-05-08  4
2022-05-22  1
2022-05-29  5
2022-06-05  1
2022-06-12  10
2022-06-19  64
2022-06-26  4
2022-07-10  800
2022-07-17  300
2022-07-24  207
2022-07-31  3002
2022-08-07  2") |> mutate(dt=as.numeric(DateObserved))

dt_seq <- seq(from=min(df_1$dt),
              to = max(df_1$dt))

dt_seq_pretty_indx <- seq(from=min(df_1$dt),
                          to = max(df_1$dt),
                          length.out=6)
dt_seq_pretty <- seq(from=min(df_1$DateObserved),
                     to = max(df_1$DateObserved),
                     length.out=6)


plot(df_1$dt,
     df_1$Value, xaxt = "n")
axis(side=1,
     at = dt_seq_pretty_indx,
     labels=dt_seq_pretty)



myloess <- loess(Value ~ dt,df_1,span = 0.4)

pred <- predict(myloess,newdata = data.frame(dt=dt_seq))

lines(x=dt_seq,
      y=pred)

library(Hmisc)
wq <- wtd.quantile(x=dt_seq,
             weights = pred,
             probs = c(.25,.75))

abline(v=wq[1],col="blue")
abline(v=wq[2],col="blue")
print(as.Date(wq,origin="1970-01-01"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works great. 
Is there any way to do this without fitting a model though? (apologies if that's a silly question)

Comment: Indeed, you could do something with your exact sparse datapponts, (pick any day before and after your one spoke point?) or you could use some method of populating the gaps; there are infinity choices.